# Override Devise sessions controller to trigger "confirm your email" email when signing in with unconfirmed account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the `confirmable` feature in Devise. When someone tries to sign in to an account that has not been confirmed, Devise automatically redirects them back to the sign in page with the error message:

`×You have to confirm your email address before continuing.`

Is there a way (possibly overriding the sessions controller with my own) to (1) trigger another "Confirm my email" email to be sent to the user at that point?; and (2) change the translation language to add the words `A confirmation email has just been sent to you.` to the alert message?

For the first question, I have previously used `@user.send_confirmation_instructions` in another controller, but don't know how to get it working in the Sessions Controller without potentially breaking the rest of the Devise sign in code.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to override the whole controller, or even a method in that. You should only use a custom controller if you want to make more significant changes.

### custom flash messages

The messaging rendered by devise is all defined in the locale. See https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml for all of the strings devise uses.

You can override each of these strings in your own English locale. Will that be enough customisation?

### custom email content

You can create custom views for any device method. See the guide at https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-views

This will allow you to generate the default view files for the email which is sent and then you can edit those. It only gets tricky if you want to pass additional data to the email. Let us know if you stumble on that.

Comment: Yes - your customisation point is spot on, thanks!

For the second point though, I don't want to change the email content or the views - I want to trigger the sending of the email (likely using @user.send_confirmation_instructions) when they try to sign in but have not confirmed their account. I'm fairly sure that requires fiddling around with the GET (signin) endpoint in the sessions controller?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I misunderstood the second point.